# The content exceeds the ViewController view, How could i show my lengthy contents in screen by scrolling?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller

I am having more lines of contents which exceeds the ViewController height, I want to show it in same screen by scrolling. Is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

Use a `UIScrollView` and put your contents in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIScrollView or UITableView for the same.

Add all views as subviews of one super view say containerView. Add containerView as sub-view of UIScrollView. Do not forget set appropriate content size of UIScrollViiew. You can do it by proper autolayout or programatically as

```
CGRect contentRect = CGRectZero;
for (UIView *view in self.scrollView.subviews) {
contentRect = CGRectUnion(contentRect, view.frame);
}
self.scrollView.contentSize = contentRect.size;
```

You can also use UITableViewController with static cells. You can add view in static cells and you are good to go. UITableViewController itself manages scrolling.

Hope it helps. Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **UIScrollView** *(As @luckyShubhra and @chedabo suggested)* , you can setup the UI correctly in Storyboard in this case and have the contentsize of the UIScrollView set to the size of the viewController contained in the UIScrollView...

Then also the **UITableView** *(As @luckyShubhra suggested)*... if your data is setup to deal with as a list of NSStrings or object, this can work well...

Then if the content is a NSString, and you would use a UILabel, I would suggest changing it to a **UITextView**... This will make it possible to scroll as well. If the contents is not to be edited just change the Selectable and Editable booleans to false...

Answer (score 0):

UIScrollView or even UITextView can help that too. if it is HTML, you may consider of rendering it with UIWebView.

just make sure the control height is lesser than the view controller, then it will render the contents in a scrollable manner.